# Overflow menu with custom toolbar

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to use custom toolbar with overflow menu in android material design, but it does not work.

My toolbar:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolsbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"

        app:menu="@menu/overflow_menu"
                >
```

This code is not working:

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            when (item.itemId)
            {
                R.id.AddWorkPost -> {
                    val dialog: DialogFragment =AddQuestion()
    //                dialog.arguments=args
                    dialog.show(supportFragmentManager,"m")
                    Log.d("sd","sd")
                }
            }
            return true
        }
```

Comment: What error do you get? what does not working for you?

Comment: No errors but no trigger at all